# ajax activate pop up upon success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

There is a pop up dialog box activated by a button with the following code:

```
<div class="button-wrap"><button data-dialog="somedialog" class="trigger">Open Dialog</button></div>
```

The code that gets the pop up to activate upon button click is here:

```
<script src="js/classie.js"></script>
<script src="js/dialogFx.js"></script>
<script>
    (function() {

        var dlgtrigger = document.querySelector( '[data-dialog]' ),
            somedialog = document.getElementById( dlgtrigger.getAttribute( 'data-dialog' ) ),
            dlg = new DialogFx( somedialog );

        dlgtrigger.addEventListener( 'click', dlg.toggle.bind(dlg) );

    })();
</script>
```

Whereby the trigger button has the data-attribute data-dialog="somedialog".

The html code for the dialog box itself is here:

```
<div id="somedialog" class="dialog">
                    <div class="dialog__overlay"></div>
                    <div class="dialog__content">
                        <div class="morph-shape">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 560 280" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                                <rect x="3" y="3" fill="none" width="556" height="276"/>
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dialog-inner">
                            <h2><strong>Howdy</strong>, I'm a dialog box</h2>
                            <div><button class="action" data-dialog-close>Close</button></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**NOTE** : that both the dialog-box and the button to activate it share the attribute "somedialog"

However, i want to integrate the pop up with ajax, such that the pop up is automatically called (no binding) when ajax returns success/done. My ajax code is working and the HTML/CSS code for the pop up is also already coded.

The issue is how can i turn the button activation into an automatic activation upon ajax success?

Thanks!

Comment: which plugin you are using for popup?

Answer (score 0):

basically `dlg.toggle.bind(dlg)` is having the click functionality.

just trigger that like this

```
dlg.toggle.bind(dlg)()
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/ed0coLdw/1/)

Comment: hi, doesn't work, i think  dlg = new DialogFx( somedialog ); is also important as it creates the object, but even having the two sentences doesn't bring up any pop up upon success/error

Comment: i have checked this code with the demo server and its working fine. please make sure that all the variables which are created are in GLOBAL scope.

Comment: hi there, do you have the link to the jsfiddle that can help me out alittle? thanks!

Comment: hi there, i actually got it to work, You just need to append these two lines in your ajax code: window.dlg = new DialogFx( window.somedialog );
     dlg.toggle.bind(dlg)();

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is actually to add just these two lines in your ajax code to append the new modal:

window.dlg = new DialogFx( window.somedialog );
dlg.toggle.bind(dlg)();